# how to use scipy.stats.discrete.expect to calculate discrete expected value?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

First of all, I am new to `scipy`. It is a probably a rookie question. I am not sure how to use `scipy.discrete.expect` to calculate the following function, given discrete input: 1,2,3

```
m = lambda k: (0.12*np.sin((2*np.pi*k)/3 + np.pi/2))**2
k = 1,2,3
```

for now, I wrote a small function myself, before I know how to use the standard function.

```
input_k = [np.array([1]),np.array([2]),np.array([3])]

def discrete_expect_mk(input_k):
    temp_k = []
    for i in input_k:
        temp_k.append(m(i))
    return np.array([np.mean(temp_k)])

    discrete_expect_mk(input_k)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can use [`scipy.stats.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html#scipy.stats.randint)`(low=1, high=4).expect(m)`

In the more general case of an arbitrary uniform multinomial with alphabet `k`, you can use

```
uniform_dist = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(k, np.ones(k)/len(k)))
result = uniform_dist.expect(m)
```

Comment: Thank you Eric. you are the man. this is exactly I was hoping for!

Comment: @W.S.: See my update for a way of doing this for non-sequential k

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `for` loop in this case:

```
import numpy as np
m = lambda k: (0.12*np.sin((2*np.pi*k)/3 + np.pi/2))**2
k=np.arange(1,4) # k = array([1, 2, 3])
print (m(k))
# array([ 0.0036,  0.0036,  0.0144])
print (np.mean(m(k)))
# 0.0072
```

If you want to use `scipy.stats.rv_discrete`, make sure `m(k)`'s are probabilities, i.e. they add up to 1.

```
from scipy import stats
pk = m(k)
pk /= np.sum(m(k)) # making sure they add up to 1
func = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(k, pk))
func.expect()
# 2.5
```

If you insist on using `rv_discrete` and all `m`'s have the same probability, you might use:

```
from scipy import stats
pk = np.ones_like(m(k))/len(m(k))
func = stats.rv_discrete(name='custm', values=(m(k), pk))
func.mean()
# 0.0072
```

Comment: True. Thanks for the feedback. I want to know how to use the standard scipy.discrete.expect method to calculate expected value, instead of writing a function myself.

Comment: @W.S.: Do you mean `scipy.stats.rv_discrete.expect` function?

Comment: yes. for instance. or anything fall under scipy.stats with any distribution. in other words, which discrete distribution should I use to generate sequential integer by using scipy.distribution ?

Comment: Thanks. but I did not get the right value. maybe I did something wrong. the right value should be : 0.0072. pk /= np.sum(m(input_k)), I get a strange result: array([  2.16172782e+15,   2.16172782e+15,  -4.32345564e+15])

Comment: @W.S.: Do you want the average of `m`'s or the expected value of a probability distribution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130356/discussion-between-mahdi-and-w-s).

Comment: It should be uniform, so equal chance for all 3 values. it would be same as np.mean(pk) = 0.0072

Comment: sorry @Mahdi , i need to give the accepted answer to Eric's answer below. his answer is exactly matching what I was looking for you.

Comment: @W.S.: Of course, his answer is evidently better (and shorter)! :)